# Как найти повторяющиеся числа в массиве, если их несколько?

Tags: java, c#, массивы

Только начала заниматься программированием. Не могу решить данную задачу. Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: [Домашние задания надо выполнять самостоятельно. Если у вас возник вопрос по домашнему заданию, не просите его сделать за вас. Задайте конкретный вопрос о проблеме, которую вы не можете решить. Программирование — это то, в чём надо разбираться самому, либо не заниматься им вовсе.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Условие описано слишком неконкретно, поэтому в общих чертах могу сказать: возьмите вспомогательный `HashSet` в которых помещайте все встреченные числа. Если какое-то число уже присутствует в хэшсете - значит, это дубль, добавляете к итоговому `List<int>`. За один обход массива найдёте всё, что нужно.

Comment: можно еще через LINQ сгрупировать по значению. Потом сделать пары - значение+каунт встречаний. Кода будет меньше чем у варианте АК, но он немного сложнее и медленнее работает. И да, ответ касается шарпа. С джавой не прокатит. Пожалуста, проставляй теги не указывая лишних - это против правил ресурса.

Answer (score 1):

Кстати да, можно же написать linq-однострочник :) Спасибо @Andrew что напомнил:

```
var source = new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7 };

var result = source.GroupBy(x => x)
                   .Select(x => new { Key = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
                   .Where(x => x.Count > 1)
                   .Select(x => x.Key);
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот мне будет смешно если вопрос на самом деле по java

Comment: вангую что если топикстартер не домашку решает - ему важно понять алгоритм, а он есть в комментах. Вообще же удалить ответ недолгое.

Comment: Ну а если решает домашку и на шарпе - вряд ли примут ответ на основе LINQ. Я бы не принял такой ответ от человека, когда он не может это же решить без линка)))